# RecyclerView within ViewPager not working

Tags: java, android

so I'm working on an app that utilizes a fixed 2 tabs within a view pager. I have a `RecyclerView` inside of a `ViewPager` but the `RecyclerView` is not responding to horizontal swipes. I have disabled swiping to change pages within the ViewPager by overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`. I've called `setFocusable(false)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)` on the view pager to no avail. Any ideas?

```
    // ViewPager code
    pager = (NoSwipePager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setFocusable(false);
    pager.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    adapter = new FormTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), form, editing);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    tabs = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
    tabs.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
    tabs.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A52A2A"));
    tabs.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    // RecyclerView code
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(act);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) rv.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    elementsAdapter = new ElementsAdapter(listener, act, new LinkedList<>(elements), editing);
    rv.setAdapter(elementsAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new ElementTouchHelper(elementsAdapter);
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);
```

Comment: Could you share your xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to off viewpager swaping both are not working at same time.

Too disable swip of viewpager use below code

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true; // default swipe enable is true
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }
    // true - enable swipe 
    // false - disable swipe
    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } 
}
```

and use below code while using viewpager in .xml file

```
<package.MyViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/viewPager" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Hope these answer helps you.

These same approach you can use use it for recyclerview also if you required in future.

Hope these help you.

Comment: View Pager swiping is already disabled, however the RecyclerView still isn't working.

Comment: make custom view as viewpager add OnTouch on It and return default behavior. follow the same steps as MyViewPager and don't use any swipe Boolean their it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment to show RecycleView.
For example:
You will create a class Adapter to manage.

```
public class HomeFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragment = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

public HomeFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(fragmentManager);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    mFragment.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitle.add(title);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragment.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragment.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitle.get(position);
}
```

}

And after that you will add more fragment which include any RecycleView you need.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
Menu mMenu;

public HomeFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_home, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_home);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_home);

    if(viewPager != null){
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    HomeFragmentAdapter adapter = new HomeFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ExpenseFragment(), "Expense");
    adapter.addFragment(new IncomeFragment(), "Income");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

T hope it could been help you.