# how Use ViewPager, TabLayout and RecyclerView and disable ViewPager swipe?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I used TabLayout with ViewPager, into ViewPager I have two RecyclerView.
when I disable viewPager swipe with under methods:

```
view_pager.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true }
```

or

```
view_pager.beginFakeDrag()
```

and use customViewPager on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777097/recyclerview-within-viewpager-not-working). but still, I have the problem.

it's work good. and recyclerView work perfectly. but when we are in start or end item in RecyclerView and try swipe into RecyclerView noting happen into RecyclerView but my ViewPager will swipe slowly to another page and it's really bad. I wanna stop paging in ViewPager with swipe and just change page with Above Tab. may please help me to fix this happen!?

Comment: You should really try and google this because I learned that beginFakeDrag doesn't work and found a good alternative in 15 seconds

Comment: I know ZUNJAE. I said that just for now I'm searching about this. if you know sth that help me with this please share with me. thanks